# Flutter alert dialog setState not changing

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to change some bool values in my Dialog. I am doing like this

```
   showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (context, setState) {
            bool testBool = true;
            return Dialog(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius:
                  BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                  side: BorderSide(
                      color:
                      kPrimaryColor)), //this right here
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){
                  print(testBool);
                  setState((){
                    testBool = !testBool;

                  });
                  print(testBool);
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 525,
                  width: width * 0.85,
                  child:
                  Text('12313', style: TextStyle(color: testBool? Colors.red : Colors.green),),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
```

But its not changing the color, I mean to say its not changing `testBool` state in Dialog.

Comment: `bool testBool = true;`should be above the `StatefulBuilder.builder`,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is fine but you're putting the `bool` condition within the `builder` which is why every time you call `setState` it is again set to `true`.

```dart
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    bool testBool = true; // This flag should be here.
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, setState) {
        // ... 
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the variable `testbool` outside the `StatefulBuilder`, because whenever you perform `setState`, the program under `StatefulBuilder` rebuilds and so the variavle `testbool` is defined again.

Answer (score 1):

As CopsOnRoad mentioned the `bool testBool = true;` is in the wrong place.  When you call setState, it rebuilds the widget and when it rebuilds the widget it defines testBool and sets it to true.  The variable testBool should be a field in the state class the dialog is being built in.